BIOS update on HP Elitedesk 800 G3 Mini?
My HP EliteDesk 800 G3 Mini has a newer BIOS update, but it only has the Windows download option. I'm running Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS. Is there a guide that I need to follow?

HP EliteDesk 800 G3 Mini

Do you really need the BIOS update?

isn't the BIOS update performed by selection the boot menu at startup?

@graham I think the BIOS update that Kevin is referring to HP EliteDesk 800 G3 DM System BIOS (P21) 00.02.49 Rev.A March 11, 2024.

BIOS updates come with masses of security patches these days. If you care for the machine and it's not some offline legacy system, then yes, you really really need the updates.

Ubuntu repositories don't contain BIOS or UEFI firmware updates. This is because the update process is specific to the motherboard manufacturer and model, and updating the BIOS/UEFI can be risky if it's not done correctly.
There is no such thing as a universal OS solution for installing UEFI updates across different hardware vendors because it would be potentially risky. In order to update your UEFI, you'll typically need to download the update from the motherboard manufacturer's website (e.g. the Windows download option that you mentioned) and follow their instructions. Make sure your device has a stable power supply (e.g. plug in the device's power cable or adapter) during the update process to avoid any interruptions.
The BIOS update that you mentioned, if it's HP EliteDesk 800 G3 DM System BIOS (P21) 00.02.49 Rev.A, most likely refers to a UEFI firmware update. Even though it uses the term BIOS in its name you can't use a legacy Windows program like FreeDOS to install it. It's just one more thing that makes life difficult.

You can connect it to the internet and enter the BIOS using the Esc key at boot-up. From there you may get the diagnostic menu, exit and confirm yes.  Then you should get another graphical menu. If you have the .bin format of the file. It says it needs to be in a folder "EFI\HP\BIOS\New" If you have an internet connection, you can simply enter the BIOS and there is an option to update. I believe it is the second one on the Main tab. Select the Update BIOS at HP.com, usually it's selected by default. This will setup the NIC to connect to HP and download from there. The next screen you should see is a confirmation showing you the current, latest, and rollback versions available to you.

I've upgraded a very similar machine succesfully by running the stupid downloaded exe file in wine. This prompts to accept the license and unpacks the software. Then you can find the .bin file inside and place it in EFI/HP/BIOS/New like the update function says.
If the updater can't find the file, check that you've downloaded the file for the exact machine you have. The file name (and obviously content) differs!
